# Python - pyqt5 - Set text to qtextbrowser with different colors

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I have a **String array** which contains **correctly spelled** words and **misspelled** words. I want to set all those words to a `qtextbrowser` and I want to make misspelled words **red** color.

```
wordlist = ['correct1', 'correct2', 'incorrect1', 'correct3', 'incorrect2']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the misspelled words in an html tag and set the inline style to display red.

```
def check_misspelled(self, word):
    if ...:  # check if word is misspelled here
        word = '<span style=\" color: #ff0000;\">%s</span>' % word
    self.text_browser.append(word)
```

Comment: `self.text_browser.append(word)` this method gives output in newline each time. So every word is in a newline. Can you give me a solution for that?

Comment: Collect the words in a list and append it to the text browser at once with a join statement.  `self.text_browser.append(' '.join(x for x in collected_words))`

Comment: color doesn't apply for numbers. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it works with numbers for me.

Comment: Not only for numbers but also for special characters, It doesn't work for me. I think the reason is I'm using numbers with my native language font (සිංහල). When I use numbers with English It works.

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor = self.textBrowser.textCursor()
cursor.insertHtml('''<p><span style="color: red;">{} </span>'''.format(word))
```

This will fix 'append to newline every time' issue.